# how to filter out cells with wrong format in data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I would like to write a function or use a command that checks if the ID follows a specific format, namely the ID has to be 9 digit long and the first digit has to be an alphabet. If it doesn't, then I want to filter out that row corresponding to that ID number. For example, I have this DataFrame (call it df):

```
         ID          status
   0    B12345678   graduated
   1    C12345678   graduated
   2    A12345678   in progress
   3    111111111   unknown
   4    A3B111111   unknown
   5    A12 unknown
```

using `df = df[df['ID'].str.len()==9]`, I can filter out the last row to get

```
         ID          status
    0   B12345678   graduated
    1   C12345678   graduated
    2   A12345678   in progress
    3   111111111   unknown
    4   A3B111111   unknown
```

But row 3 and 4 are still not the right format and I need to filter that out as well. What would be an efficient way to do this?

I tried

```
df = df[df['ID'].isdigit()]
```

but I got an error that says:"'Series' object has no attribute 'isdigit'"

My data frame code is:

```
   students = [('ID', ['B12345678', 'C12345678',  'A12345678','111111111','A3B111111','A12']),
 ('status', ['graduated',  'graduated','in progress','unknown','unknown','unknown'])
 ]


df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(students)
```

Answer (score 2):

use [Series.str.match()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) with a corresponding RegEx:

```
In [4]: df[df['ID'].str.match(r'[A-Z]\d{8}')]
Out[4]:
          ID       status
0  B12345678    graduated
1  C12345678    graduated
2  A12345678  in progress
```

or

```
df[df['ID'].str.match(r'[A-Z]\d{8}', case=False)]
```

if the first letter might occur in lower case as well

Comment: Thanks. How would I do this if these data were streaming in? For example, how would I check just for only one row or for one ID element (i.e. B12345678)? I keep getting an error that says: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'" when I try to check it just for one element